# How to add Additonal charge on COD in magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.1.8, cash-on-delivery

I want to add additional charge as COD payment method in Magento 2.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can try payment fee extension 
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-payment-fee.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below free extension for the same.

https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee

It will add configured extra fee for COD.

Comment: hi kisan, this extension is not working for invoice. extra fee not added in invoice total.

Comment: this is not working magento 2.1.3 version